# What is the best way to handle orientation change in Android

Tags: screen-orientation, orientation-changes

What is the best way to handle orientation change in Android? Is it by adding `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"` to the Manifest? By bundling everything in `onSavedInstanceState()` or by using fragments?

Comment: It's my experience that configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" does not allow the activity to access layout-port and layout-land files.  Also, repositioning views in onConfigurationChanged() can have unpredictable results(widths are truncated, dp to px conversions can be difficult)

Comment: I'd say [fra](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) [gme](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html#headlessfragments2) [nts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html). `android:configChanges` is broken since you'd need to actually handle the config changes (like land to port) yourself.

Comment: awesome links.  Thanks!(I wish I'd seen them a few days ago)